# Getting currenttitle in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

The usual way of getting section names in `fancyhdr` headers is by doing:
 `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}`

However, this doesn't get subsections, subsubsections, paragraphs, nor subparagraphs. I'd like the header to show the name of the last section created up to the current page, no matter if it's a section or a subparagraph.

This of course seems to match `\currenttitle` from the `titleref` package.

But unfortunately this doesn't work for getting \currenttitle in the header:
`\renewcommand{\currenttitle}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}` (yes, I know `\thesection` is wrong, but I'm first trying to get the current title name, fixing the number will come later).

Are there any workarounds for getting the current title (and its number) in a header by `fancyhdr`?

Example which I'd like to modify so that the header displays the last section/subsection/subsubsection/paragraph/subparagraph in the page:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{14pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
   \fancyhead{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post an example? `titleref` doesn't use the titles of `subsection` etc.

Comment: Example added to the post. It shows the usual `fancyhdr` behavior. I wish to change it so that it honors all hierarchical levels of sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: many levels]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\paragraphmark}[1]{\markright{\theparagraph\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subparagraphmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubparagraph\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{14pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
   \fancyhead{}%
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \section{section}
  \kant[1-4]
  \subsection{subsection}
  \kant[5-7]
  \subsubsection{subsubsection}
  \kant[8-9]
  \paragraph{paragraph}
  \kant[10-12]
  \subparagraph{subparagraph}
  \kant[13]
  \section{another section}
  \kant[14-15]
\end{document}
```

However, you should use `geometry` to set the page dimensions:

[image: adjusted page layout]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=14pt,vcentering]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\paragraphmark}[1]{\markright{\theparagraph\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subparagraphmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubparagraph\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
   \fancyhead{}%
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \section{section}
  \kant[1-4]
  \subsection{subsection}
  \kant[5-7]
  \subsubsection{subsubsection}
  \kant[8-10]
  \paragraph{paragraph}
  \kant[11-14]
  \subparagraph{subparagraph}
  \kant[15]
  \section{another section}
  \kant[16-18]
\end{document}
```

Note that `fancyhdr` is warning you that the use of `E` is useless in a single-sided document.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Yes, I'm aware of the single-sided warning, and, BTW, when changing it to two-sided, the line `\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}`must be changed to `\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\rightmark}` if I want this on both even and odd pages. Also, one question: Is it correct the result from moving the `headheight` setting to the `geometry` package? Looking at the second result, I see the white space at the bottom unpleasant if compared to the top of the page. However, on my original code, the top and the bottom are more balanced, and I tend to believe they're more correct there.

Comment: @user2811963 Yes, it is correct. But `geometry` adjusts other things. If you prefer a more even top/bottom balance, you can add `vcentering`. Please see edited answer above for an example modified in this way. And, yes, with `twoside` you'd need that. I left it from your original example because I wasn't sure what exactly you wanted.